# Docker Toolbox for Windows 7 Professional

Tags: windows-7

Where can I download it from? The current Docker Toolbox version doesn't support Win7.

I don't need only an older version of Docker, that I can download from [here](https://download.docker.com/win/static/stable/x86_64/), but a full Toolbox.

From [this article](https://stefanscherer.github.io/yes-you-can-docker-on-windows-7/) we can learn that Windows 7 **Enterprise** is actually needed, but I remember some year ago I managed to install Docker Toolbox on Win 7 Pro.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I've found it on [GitHub](https://github.com/docker/toolbox/releases):

Version 17.06.2-ce works fine